# VSCode: ANSI Colors in Terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, ansi-escape

How do I print text in ansi colors in the terminal with python?
I have this code to test what code has what effect on the text:

```
for i in range(0, 55):
    print(f"\033[{i}mAt {i} THIS happens! \033[0m")
```

But all I see is:

```
←[0mAt 0 THIS happens! ←[0m
←[1mAt 1 THIS happens! ←[0m
←[2mAt 2 THIS happens! ←[0m
←[3mAt 3 THIS happens! ←[0m
←[4mAt 4 THIS happens! ←[0m
...
```

**[It works as intended in the online editor repl.it.](https://repl.it/repls/VeneratedBarrenSandbox)**

I know that there are the `terminal.ansi` colors in the theme settings, but how do I access them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use the [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/) package to support ANSI sequences on Windows.

```
import colorama
colorama.init()

# your code with ansi sequences here
```

Edit: This method is platform agnostic (ANSI sequences will not be modified on terminals which support them) and allows you to use raw ANSI sequences in strings, as well as providing you with color definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Escape sequences will vary by terminal, and if stdout isn't a tty, things will get weird for you.

The easiest way to print colors to the terminal without relying on these sequences is with the [`blessings` package](https://blessings.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). The following will print `hello` in red and `world` in green (for example):

```
from blessings import Terminal
term = Terminal()
print(term.red("hello"), term.green("world"))
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  There's an old Unix utility called tput (Terminal Put) which can be used from shell scripts to look up the escape sequences which are appropriate for your terminal (as per your TERM environment setting).  But it's a hoary inscrutable mess.

https://linux.101hacks.com/ps1-examples/prompt-color-using-tput/

Under the hood blessings and similar modules in Python are referring to the same terminfo or termcap APIs in C.